# Leap years in pandas.DatetimeIndex.dayofyear

Tags: python, pandas

I want to calculate the mean depending of the day of the year from a time series with data over many years. Thereby I encountered a problem when dealing with leap years which is shown in the example below.

```
ind=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31', freq='d')
dat=np.arange(1,367,1)
ser=pd.Series(dat, index=ind)
```

The resulting Series has 366 entries because of the leap year.

I removed the entry for 29th February manually by:

```
ser=ser[~((ser.index.month==2)&(ser.index.day==29))]
```

As expected the series has afterwards only 365 entries.

When I the calculate the mean of the day of the year by:

```
doy_mean=ser.groupby(ser.index.dayofyear).mean()
```

I get again a series with 366 entries. Any ideas how to deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: All you're doing is removing 29th February, the last day of the year will still have dayofyear value of 366. So you could remove the last day of the year or group on month and day value if you just want to remove the 29th Feb

Comment: Check `len(doy_mean)` it should be 365.

Comment: Thanks! I want to calculate temperature means from a 30 year timeseries. If I goupby dayofyear the value for day 365 is calculated from the value of 31 of december for non-leap years and 30 december for leap years. When grouping by month and day I can avoid this mistake.

Answer (score 0):

I am not following your complete logic here, but you can use this as a starting point.

```
ind=pd.DatetimeIndex(start='2016-01-01', end='2016-12-31', freq='d')
dat=np.arange(1,367,1)
ser=pd.Series(dat, index=ind)

ser=ser[~((ser.index.month==2)&(ser.index.day==29))]
ser = ser.ne(0).cumsum()

ser.groupby(ser.values).mean()
```

Output:

```
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
5    5
...
361    361
362    362
363    363
364    364
365    365
dtype: int32
```